# ExtJS with TinyMCE - unknown dependency error

Tags: extjs, extjs4, tinymce, extjs4.2

I am using [TinyMCE plugin](http://harrydeluxe.github.io/extjs-ux/example/form/tinymce.html) with ExtJS 4.2.

When i try to create an EXTJS application build, i am getting the following error:

```
com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : tinyMCE.WindowManager
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465310/minifying-extjs-and-tinymce

Answer (score 0):

Try to add tinymce windowManager in your app.js

```
Ext.require(['Ext.ux.form.TinyMCETextAreaWindowManager',
]);
```

it will help you to fix this error also when you are using sencha cmd for building the application for deployment it is necessary to add this in app.js