# Minifying ExtJS and Tinymce

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using the [TinyMCE plugin](http://harrydeluxe.github.io/extjs-ux/example/form/tinymce.html).  When I try to build a production app with Sencha CMD, I am getting this error:

```
com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : tinyMCE.WindowManager
```

Does anyone know how to minify this?

Answer (score 0):

found here a solution 
 https://sencha-webstack1-1540763642.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/forum/showthread.php?275091-Error-executing-sencha-app-refresh&p=1008593&viewfull=1

So for me works this:
 just put next lines into TinyMCETextArea.js

```
// @define tinymce.WindowManager
// @require ./tinymce/tiny_mce_src.js

Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.TinyMCETextAreaWindowManager', {
    extend: 'tinymce.WindowManager',
```